# How can you plot data from a .txt file using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a txt file using matplotlib but I keep getting this error message. I'm not that familiar with python, as I started learning a couple of weeks ago. The text file is formatted like (it is 2048 rows long):

```
6876.593750  1
6876.302246  1
6876.003418  0
```

I would like to plot the data from the txt. file.
The error message is [IndexError: list index out of range]

The code I'm using is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open("Alpha_Particle.txt") as f:
data = f.read()

data = data.split('\n')

x = [row.split(' ')[0] for row in data]
y = [row.split(' ')[1] for row in data]

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.set_title("Plot title")    
ax1.set_xlabel('x label')
ax1.set_ylabel('y label')

ax1.plot(x,y, c='r', label='the data')

leg = ax1.legend()

plt.show()
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Upon first glance it looks like there are two spaces between your x data point and your y data point in the .txt file. You split it in your list comprehension along a single space, which would return you a list of the x point, a space, and a y point.

Comment: data has four lines, not three

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're just reading in the data wrong. Here's a cleaner way:

```
with open('Alpha_Particle.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    x = [line.split()[0] for line in lines]
    y = [line.split()[1] for line in lines]

x
['6876.593750', '6876.302246', '6876.003418']

y
['1', '1', '0']
```

Answer (score 7):

maybe you can use pandas or numpy

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('data.txt',sep='\s+',header=None)
data = pd.DataFrame(data)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = data[0]
y = data[1]
plt.plot(x, y,'r--')
plt.show()
```

this is my data

```
1   93
30  96
60  84
90  84
120 48
150 38
180 51
210 57
240 40
270 45
300 50
330 75
360 80
390 60
420 72
450 67
480 71
510 7
540 74
570 63
600 69
```

[The output looked like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOssH.png)

With Numpy, you can also try it with the following method

```
import numpy  as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.loadtxt('data.txt')


x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]
plt.plot(x, y,'r--')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

[Chris Arena](https://stackoverflow.com/users/635148/chris-arena)'s answer is neat. Please keep in mind that you are saving str into a list. If you want to plot x and y using matplotlib, I suggest to change the format from 'str' to 'int' or 'float':

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    x = [float(line.split()[0]) for line in lines]
    y = [float(line.split()[1]) for line in lines]
plt.plot(x ,y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution would be to remove the 4th element in data like this:

```
data.pop()
```

Place it after

```
data = data.split('\n')
```