# How to plot multiple set of data from same text file in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have data file say `data.txt` as,

```
1 10 
2 20
3 30
4 41
5 49

1 11
2 19
3 32
4 37
5 52
```

**Note there are two set of data**. I want to plot them in same graph. In `gnuplot` it is very simple we just have to run `plot 'data.txt' with line` and we will get a graph like this,
[image]

Actually I have 50 such set in the same data file. I have just started learning `python`. I want to plot this data file using `numpy` and `matplotlib`.

There are similar threads in this forum like,

[How to plot data from multiple two column text files with legends in Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248812/how-to-plot-data-from-multiple-two-column-text-files-with-legends-in-matplotlib)

[How can you plot data from a .txt file using matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38532298/how-can-you-plot-data-from-a-txt-file-using-matplotlib)

but I could not find anything similar to my issue.

Comment: Can you show the code that you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea can be to read the complete file, split it at the positions where a double line break occurs, `.split('\n\n')` and read in each part using `numpy.loadtxt`.

```
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename="data.txt"
with open(filename) as f:
    data = f.read()

data = data.split('\n\n')

for d in data:
    ds = np.loadtxt(StringIO(unicode(d)))
    plt.plot(ds[:,0],ds[:,1])

plt.show()
```

Comment: `unicode` gave a NameError while running with `python3` because `Python 3` renamed the `unicode` type to `str`. After replacing it with `str` it worked, thanks for your help.