# how can i plot data from .txt file using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot data from .txt file.

here is my .txt file (test.txt)

```
0  81       
1  78       
2  76
3  74
4  81
5  79
6  80
7  81
8  83
9  83
10  83
11  82
  .
  .
22  81
23  80
```

I have looked at similar question

([How can you plot data from a .txt file using matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38532298/how-can-you-plot-data-from-a-txt-file-using-matplotlib))
but I have two problems.

Frist problem, Figure's y startpoint is fixed at the smallest of the .txt file's data(Y)

I have tried **set_ylim or ymin**. but it doesn't work..

Second problem, x axis is putting 10 before 2.

I refer to a lot of data, but the result was not good.

I want to make it like the [following graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiQEi.png)

this is my py code and [my actual graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbjNT.png)(.png file)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open('test.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

x = [line.split()[0] for line in lines]
y = [line.split()[1] for line in lines]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.set_title("SMP graph")
ax1.set_xlabel('hour')
ax1.set_ylabel('smp')
ax1.bar(x,y, width=0.7)

fig1=plt.gcf()
plt.show()
plt.draw()
fig1.savefig('test.png')
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are treating your numbers as `string` when you read them from file so you get lexicographical ordering. Cast them to `int` and the order becomes correct.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open('test.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    x = [int(line.split()[0]) for line in lines]
    y = [int(line.split()[1]) for line in lines]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.set_title("SMP graph")
ax1.set_xlabel('hour')
ax1.set_ylabel('smp')
ax1.bar(x,y, width=0.7)

fig1=plt.gcf()
plt.show()
plt.draw()
```

Think you can take it from here?

Comment: thank you for your help.now it works. really thanks a lot